# Formula for sorting a list of two values

Tags: sorting

I have one problem during building my online service and need your help:

I have a list of workers who are working on some task. They can be rewarded for their results or not. Of course they try to get as many tasks as possible and get rewarded.

Now I need to be able to sort these workers in my online catalog, but I need some formula for that.

Problem: A new worker can get a reward for his first task and be 100% successful. Rationally, though, a worker with score 99/100 should be higher because he has more experience and probably is better than the novice.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Is this really a Mathematica question? If so, you should give some context how the rest of your system is implemented.

Comment: It's not about the implementation. I just need some formula / coefficient for sorting the workers.

Comment: This is actually vague because there can be lot of parameters (age,experience,records,mistakes..etc)that decide who is more worthy. This is more of optimization problem for which there are different strategies(like Bee colony optimization). There is no standard formula for this.

Comment: But then it's off-topic, as this site is about _Mathematica_, the computer algebra software.

Comment: My advice is to hire a mathematical consultant. Why do you expect free help for your commercial venture?

Answer (score 0):

There are many such formulas.  Unless you define better what you want, we can't find *the one* you are looking for.  As you say, percentage is one formula.  Percentage plus number of tasks is another.  Percentage minus (100 divided by tasks) is yet a third.